# How do I redirect back to the source page after the user submits a comment?

Tags: comments

How can I access the nid of the current page so that a user can submit their comment and be returned back to the page they just commented from. Here's what I am proposing...

```
function mymodule_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $nid = arg(2);
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'mymodule/' . $nid;
}
```

...to be placed in `template.php`. However using `$node -> nid` (referenced in comment.module) or `$nid` (referenced in my custom module) throws an undefined error. How can I access the nid to complete my redirecting URL? Or is there a better way of acheiving this?

I believe this is the part of comment.module that I need to hook into and modify - so in a wider sense my question is about hooking into a core module and modifying its function:

```
/**
 * Process comment form submissions; prepare the comment, store it, and set a redirection target.
 */
function comment_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $node = node_load($form_state['values']['nid']);
  $comment = comment_form_submit_build_comment($form, $form_state);
  if (user_access('post comments') && (user_access('administer comments') || $node->comment == COMMENT_NODE_OPEN)) {
    // Save the anonymous user information to a cookie for reuse.
    if (user_is_anonymous()) {
      user_cookie_save(array_intersect_key($form_state['values'], array_flip(array('name', 'mail', 'homepage'))));
    }

    comment_save($comment);
    $form_state['values']['cid'] = $comment->cid;

    // Add an entry to the watchdog log.
    watchdog('content', 'Comment posted: %subject.', array('%subject' => $comment->subject), WATCHDOG_NOTICE, l(t('view'), 'comment/' . $comment->cid, array('fragment' => 'comment-' . $comment->cid)));

    // Explain the approval queue if necessary.
    if ($comment->status == COMMENT_NOT_PUBLISHED) {
      if (!user_access('administer comments')) {
        drupal_set_message(t('Your comment has been queued for review by site administrators and will be published after approval.'));
      }
    }
    else {
      drupal_set_message(t('Your comment has been posted.'));
    }
    $query = array();
    // Find the current display page for this comment.
    $page = comment_get_display_page($comment->cid, $node->type);
    if ($page > 0) {
      $query['page'] = $page;
    }
    // Redirect to the newly posted comment.
    $redirect = array('node/' . $node->nid, array('query' => $query, 'fragment' => 'comment-' . $comment->cid));
  }
  else {
    watchdog('content', 'Comment: unauthorized comment submitted or comment submitted to a closed post %subject.', array('%subject' => $comment->subject), WATCHDOG_WARNING);
    drupal_set_message(t('Comment: unauthorized comment submitted or comment submitted to a closed post %subject.', array('%subject' => $comment->subject)), 'error');
    // Redirect the user to the node they are commenting on.
    $redirect = 'node/' . $node->nid;
  }
  $form_state['redirect'] = $redirect;
  // Clear the block and page caches so that anonymous users see the comment
  // they have posted.
  cache_clear_all();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the arg() function?

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't seem to work. Perhaps, I could install Token, create an action (redirect to URL), assign to a trigger (when new comment saved) and use the token [content:nid] to provide the node id, but it seems like a lot of overhead for just one redirect on one form.

Comment: If you're on a node, `$nid = arg(1);`. What do you mean when you say "that didn't seem to work"?

Comment: I updated the hook I'm using in template.php above to reflect my attempt to use arg(). The path is mywebsite/mymodule/1. I've tried arg(1) arg(2) and arg(3). But instead of getting redirected to mymodule/1 it goes to node/1#comment-1. I'm not even sure that I'm using the right hook. You can certainly modify the comment form with that hook, but can you modify the submit handler with it?

Comment: Sounds like you are using some sort of custom comment page? Can you give more information on that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To redirect a form after submission you would do this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Add a custom submit handler to act when the form submits.
  $form['#submit'][] = 'MYMODULE_custom_comment_submit_handler';
}

/**
 * Custom submit handler for the comment form.
 */
function MYMODULE_custom_comment_submit_handler($form, &$form_state) {
  // Redirect the user after submission
  $nid = arg(2);
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'mymodule/' . $nid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Both functions to be placed in template.php? or in my custom module? - which, by the way, implements the rendering of comments and the comments form by returning comment_node_page_additions($node) within a renderable array.

Comment: In a custom module for those. - And it should still work fine with your custom calling of comment_node_page_additions(). I would put it in the same custom module as it directly relates to the other code you have in there.

Answer (score 4):

What about using the Modules Actions, Trigger and Tokens?

Create an Action "Redirect to URL" on yoursite.com/admin/config/system/actions:
Give it a name and an target URL like "node/[comment:node:nid]".

Assign that Action to the Trigger "AFTER SAVING A NEW COMMENT" on yoursite.com/admin/structure/trigger/comment

Just my thoughts...

Answer (score 0):

Do You tried to use [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module? I always use this if I have to do a custom redirects.