# How NOT to redirect using the Rules module?

Tags: rules, comments

I have a comment form in a panel. The path to the panel is *user/[uid].*

When I post a comment I am taken to another page where all the comments are shown *(user/[uid]/comments.)* I do not want this, I want to stay on the same *user/[uid]* page.

Does anyone know how to do this using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I redirect back to the source page after the user submits a comment?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/72307/how-do-i-redirect-back-to-the-source-page-after-the-user-submits-a-comment)

Comment: No, unfortunately, it does not give the answer using the Rules module.

Answer (score 0):

A possible "remedy" for this is to use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module (indeed ...). To do so, have a look at my answer to "[How to restrict access to a node via node/12 and allow access via a path like content/sometitle?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165114/how-to-restrict-access-to-a-node-via-node-12-and-allow-access-via-a-path-like-co/165126#165126)".

Use the rule included there (within "Option 1"), and apply these changes to it:

- Adapt the regular expression within the "Rules Condition", to make it match your ***(user/[uid]/comments.)***.
- Adapt the "no_access" url to your ***user/[uid]***.
- Probably you don't want to display any message, so just remove that "Rules Action".